# getting an error saying that invalid identifier

Tags: sql, plsql

Using USING, list the vendors who have supplied a line item where the description contains 'Card' or COBOL (both case insensitive). Include the vendor name and description, with no duplicate lines in the output. Order the listing by the description.

Code:

```
SELECT v.VENDOR_NAME, li.LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
FROM VENDORS v JOIN
     INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS li
     USING (VENDOR_ID)
WHERE li.LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Card%' OR 
      li.LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%COBAL%';
```

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "LI"."VENDOR_ID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Could you give us your table structure? This error mean there aren't "VENDOR_ID" column in "INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS" table.

Comment: Are you using LI.VENDOR_ID somewhere in the query? When you use USING you can't use table aliases to refer the columns used in the USING clause. In this case, if you want to use VENDOR_ID in your query you should refer to it just as VENDOR_ID.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you just want to create a simple equi-join query.
How about trying this:

```
SELECT
  v.VENDOR_NAME
  ,li.LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
FROM
  vendors v
  ,invoice_line_items li
WHERE
  v.vendor_id = li.vendor_id
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(li.line_item_description, '(card)|(cobal)')
```

Of course, make sure you can join these two tables using VENDOR_ID column.